# Unusual use of a Boolean expression

Tags: c++, lint

This is a part of my code base
Code:

```
bool succ = true;
//below is the place where warning is there 
succ &= draw( e0.x, e0.y, e0.z, (e0.x + dir.x), (e0.y + dir.y), (e0.z + dir.z));
//------
//------
bool draw( FLOAT x, FLOAT y, FLOAT z, FLOAT p, FLOAT q, FLOAT r)  
{
    bool ret;
    ret = fun(x,y,z,p,q,r);
    return ret;
}
```

Warning :

```
Warning 514: Unusual use of a Boolean expression
Info 1786: Implicit conversion to Boolean (assignment) (int to bool)
```

I don't want to increase the line of code ,so doing this logic in one line ...can somebody will help me in resolving this issue ...

Comment: `succ = succ && draw(...)`? if you have such calls alot it might be worth to write a simple utility function for it

Comment: draw is returning bool ....so just anding the result with succ and storing the result in succ

Comment: @auselen i guess he got a bunch of draw-calls in the same function and wants to check if all succeeded

Comment: Why so concerned about making the succ assignment stay a single line, when draw() is a three-line function that does one line worth of work, and perhaps isn't needed at all?

Comment: @Daniel ,its true having lots of draw calls

Comment: Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.

--Brian Kernighan

Answer (score 4):

You have a &= there, which for these basic types is equivalent to

```
bool succ = ...;
succ = succ & draw(...);
```

However the bitwise & operator takes integer values, so succ needs to be cast to int in order to compare using bitwise  &. When you use booleans you should instead use

```
bool succ = ...;
succ = draw(...) && succ;
```

(as pointed out you have to change the order here since && is one of the very few places where c++ is actually lazily evaluating)

Notice that there is no &&= operator.

**Edit:** Actually the result of draw(...) needs to be cast to int too...

Comment: That changes the behaviour: the first will call `draw` unconditionally, while the second will only call it if `succ` is true.

Comment: i am getting below warning after doing same changes                    Assignment to strong type 'bool' in context: assignment

Comment: @mike: Well you are completely right. Edited to make it correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the equivalent behaviour without any dubious conversions between boolean and integer values with

```
succ = draw(...) && succ;
```

or

```
if (!draw(...)) succ = false;
```

Note the order of the operands in the first: `succ && draw(...)` would change the behaviour so that `draw` would only be called if `succ` were true.

Answer (score 0):

There is no construct equivalently compact for bool, because there is no &&= operator. The &= operator forces a conversion to and from int. And && forces short-circuit evaluation.

Try one of  these:

```
int succ; // define succ as integer to allow use of &=, just like in the good old days
```

OR

```
succ = draw( e0.x, e0.y, e0.z, (e0.x + dir.x), (e0.y + dir.y), (e0.z + dir.z)) && succ;
```

OR

```
succ = draw( e0.x, e0.y, e0.z, (e0.x + dir.x), (e0.y + dir.y), (e0.z + dir.z)) ? succ : false;
```

OR

```
if (!draw( e0.x, e0.y, e0.z, (e0.x + dir.x), (e0.y + dir.y), (e0.z + dir.z))) succ = false;
```